# Form Validation With Complex Type Is Invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form using this model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public User SalesManager {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

rendered like this using a DropDown given a list of Users in a HtmlHelper extension:

```
<label for="SalesManager">Sales Manager</label>
<select id="SalesManager" name="SalesManager">
  <option value="7">James Morrison</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="300">Ray Manzarek</option>
  <option value="302">Robby Krieger</option>
  <option value="302">John Densmore</option>
</select>
```

and an action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(FormCollection form)
{
  ...
}
```

I'm getting a validation `ModelState` error: `The value '302' is invalid` for the SalesManager property. How can I accept just an int value, and worry about instantiating my User later (in a ModelBinder for example). Or am I just approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<select id="SalesManager_UserId" name="SalesManager.UserId">
```

because you cannot the value `302` to a complex object such as `User`.

So the helper should look like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.User.UserId, Model.PossibleValues) %>
```

Comment: Is there not a IValueProvider or ModelBinder something I can use to handle this at the property level?

Comment: @mxmissile, I don't understand you. You have a view model => use the strongly typed helpers which will take care of generating the proper markup.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare an int property on MyModel, say SelectedUser, and change the rendered select to

```
<select id="SelectedUser" name="SelectedUser">
```

If you are using the Html helpers you can do this with.

```
HtmlHelper.ListBoxFor("SelectedUser", Model.YourSelectList")
```